# Run a script at a special time on django server

Tags: python, mysql, django, cron

I have a django project and i need the ability for executing a function at a specified time on django server.
for example you can consider that in my django project if a client request for friendship to another person if after (say) 7 days that person doesn't answer that request the request will be automatically removed.
so i want the ability of calling a function on django server at a specified time
that is stored in mysql table.

Comment: Add dates to the corresponding database records, you may create a python script then which loads the django environment and looks for the records and deletes them. The script can be fired via cronjob.

Answer (score 3):

Create a [custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-management-commands) and create a cron job to run it, also you can check some [django apps](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=django-cron&submit=search) for manage cron jobs/repetitive tasks. I know you can use it on linux (in windows should be alternatives, I my head sounds now schedule task, but must there be other)

Comment: Also check following related questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3287038/2343488
http://stackoverflow.com/q/4519829/2343488
http://stackoverflow.com/q/4519829/2343488 maybe it helps you

Comment: Unacepted after acepted why? ...did you finnaly not solve it?